# scrape multiple addresses from multiple files in scrapy

Tags: python, json, file, scrapy

I have some JSON file in a directory. In any of this files, there are some information I need. the first property i need is the links list for "start_urls" in scrapy.

every file is for a different process, so its output must be separate. So I can't put all the links in all the json files into start_urls and run them together. i have to run the spider for everyfile.

how can i do this? here is my code so far:

```
import scrapy
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import json
class HotelInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hotel_info'
    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']
    # get start urls from links list of every file
    files = [f for f in listdir('lastsecond/hotels/') if 
    isfile(join('lastsecond/hotels/', f))]
    with open('lastsecond/hotels/' + files[0], 'r') as hotel_info:
        hotel = json.load(hotel_info)
    start_urls = hotel["links"]

    def parse(self, response):
        print("all good")
```

Comment: you can create `start_urls` in [start_requests()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) using `Request(..., meta={'info':...})` and you can add extra `info` to every request and it can send this `info` to your own pipeline exporter which will use this `info` to save result to different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two methods

---

**First:**

Run spider many times with different parameters. It will need less code.

You can create batch with many lines with different arguments added manually.

First argument is output filename `-o result1.csv` which scrapy will create automatically.
Second argument is input filename `-a filename=process1.csv` with links.

```
scrapy crawl hotel_info -o result1.csv -a filename=process1.csv
scrapy crawl hotel_info -o result2.csv -a filename=process2.csv
scrapy crawl hotel_info -o result3.csv -a filename=process3.csv
...
```

a it needs only to get `filename` in `__init__`

```
import scrapy
from os.path import isfile, join
import json

class HotelInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'hotel_info'

    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']

    def __init__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs): # <-- filename
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        filename = join('lastsecond/hotels/', filename) 

        if isfile(filename):
            with open(filename) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                self.start_urls = data['links']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        yield {'url':, response.url, 'other': ...}
```

You can also use Python script with `CrawlerProcess` to run spider many times.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import HotelInfoSpider
from os.path import isfile, join
import json

files = [f for f in listdir('lastsecond/hotels/') if isfile(join('lastsecond/hotels/', f))]

for i, input_file in enumerate(files):
    output_file = 'result{}.csv'.format(i)
    c = CrawlerProcess({'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv','FEED_URI': output_file})
    c.crawl(HotelInfoSpider, filename=input_file) #input_file='process1.csv')
    c.start()
```

Or using `scrapy.cmdline.execute()`

```
import scrapy.cmdline
from os.path import isfile, join
import json

files = [f for f in listdir('lastsecond/hotels/') if isfile(join('lastsecond/hotels/', f))]

for i, input_file in enumerate(files):
    output_file = 'result{}.csv'.format(i)
    scrapy.cmdline.execute(["scrapy", "crawl", "hotel_info", "-o", output_file, "-a" "filename=" + input_file])
```

---

**Second:**

It needs more code because you have to create Pipeline Exporter which will use different files to save results.

You have to use `start_requests()` and `Request(..., meta=...)` to create `start_urls` with requests which will have `extra` data in `meta` which you can use later to save in different files.

In `parse()` you have to get this `extra` from `meta` and add to `item`.

In pipeline exporter you have to get `extra` from `item` and open different file.

```
import scrapy
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import json

class HotelInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'hotel_info'

    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']

    def start_requests(self):

        # get start urls from links list of every file
        files = [f for f in listdir('lastsecond/hotels/') if isfile(join('lastsecond/hotels/', f))]

        for i, filename in enumerate(files):
            with open('lastsecond/hotels/' + filename) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                links = data["links"]
                for url in links:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'extra': i})

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        extra = response.meta['extra']
        print('extra:', extra)

        yield {'url': response.url, 'extra': extra, 'other': ...}
```

pipelines.py

```
class MyExportPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # get extra and use it in filename
        filename = 'result{}.csv'.format(item['extra'])

        # open file for appending
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

            # write only selected elements - skip `extra`
            row = [item['url'], item['other']
            writer.writerow(row)

        return item
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'your_porject_name.pipelines.MyExportPipeline': 300,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer again. I wrote this code with extra functions but the pipeline just work on the last file i used. I have several files with several links inside it, but pipeline just save the information for the urls of last file.

Comment: as in example you have to assign to request information from which file this link came from. And then you have to use this information to save in different output file.

Comment: what does "yield" in parse function do? i have to collect some information with css and ad them to item. but how can i pass them through "yield" ?

Comment: `yield` is like `return` - it returns value and freeze function . When scrapy executes `parse()` again it will start in the same place - it is useful in parser()` if you have to return many items and `Requests`. `return` returns value but when scrapy executes `parse()` again it will starts from beginning. You have to create dictionary with your information and `yield` in `for` loop if you have many elements, or `return` if you have only one item. See dictionary in line `yield {'url': response.url, 'extra': extra, 'other': ...}`.

Comment: If you use class for information (ie. `YourItem(scrapy.Item)`) then you have to add field for `extra` info and then yield instance of your class - `item = YourItem() ;  item['extra'] = ... ; yield item`.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage all the files with a `dict`:

```
d_hotel_info = {}
for file in files:
    with open('lastsecond/hotels/' + file, 'r') as hotel_info:
        hotel = json.load(hotel_info)
    d_hotel_info[file] = hotel
```

and then when you want to output, you reference the keys of `d_hotel_info`