# Scrapy output one CSV file per start url

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to output 1 CSV file for each start_url. I made a pipeline that outputs only 1 file with information from all the urls but can't figure out how to output multiple.

**pipeline.py**

```
class CSVPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['date', 'move', 'bank', 'call', 'price']
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

    print('Starting csv blank line cleaning')
    with open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        original_list = list(reader)
        cleaned_list = list(filter(None,original_list))

    with open('%s_items_cleaned.csv' % spider.name, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        wr = csv.writer(output_file, dialect='excel')
        for data in cleaned_list:
            wr.writerow(data)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item


class SentimentPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

I've been running:

```
scrapy crawl spider -o spider.csv
```

Do I need a new command?
Very new to scrapy. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/48122080/939364?

Comment: That page is for pulling urls. I'm trying to export a CSV file each time a start_url is crawled. One spider crawl should yield one file for each url in the start_url list.

Comment: Check my answer below, should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CSV Item Pipeline like the one below in the pipelines.py file

```
class PerUrlCsvExportPipeline:

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.url_to_exporter = {}

def close_spider(self, spider):
    for exporter in self.url_to_exporter.values():
        exporter.finish_exporting()

def _exporter_for_item(self, item):
    url = item['url']
    if url not in self.url_to_exporter:
        f = open('{}.csv'.format(your_file_name), 'wb')
        exporter = CsvItemExporter(f)
        exporter.start_exporting()
        self.url_to_exporter[url] = exporter
    return self.url_to_exporter[url]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    exporter = self._exporter_for_item(item)
    exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Then add the pipeline to your settings.py file:

```
    ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'your_project_name.pipelines.PerUrlCsvExportPipeline': 300,
    }
```